# how to move or drag canvas object like circle, rectangle shapes in android canvas ? i written code but its doesnt have moving function

Tags: java, android, canvas

how to move or drag canvas object like circle, rectangle shapes in android canvas ? i have written code but its doesnt have moving function...
'this is my code i need to move canvas object like shapes circle, rectangle, etc on the canvas,but am not able to do that anyone can help
'below code is the draw shapes on canvas , am facing with the issue that how to move shapes after drawn'

```
  private void touchMove(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

        if (mColorFillMode)
            return;
        if (mCircleMode) {
            // calculate radius of the circle
            float radius = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            drawCurrentPathOnTheMostRecentBitmap();
            mPath.addCircle(mX, mY, radius, Path.Direction.CW);

        } else if (mLineMode) {

            drawCurrentPathOnTheMostRecentBitmap();
            mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
            mPath.lineTo(x, y);

        } else if (mRectangleMode) {
            drawCurrentPathOnTheMostRecentBitmap();
            //Draws Rectangle
            mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
            mPath.lineTo(x, mY);
            mPath.moveTo(x, mY);
            mPath.lineTo(x, y);
            mPath.moveTo(mX, mY);
            mPath.lineTo(mX, y);
            mPath.moveTo(mX, y);
            mPath.lineTo(x, y);
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);

          } else {
      
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    private void touchUp(float x, float y) {
        if (mColorFillMode)
            return;

        mImages.push(new Image(mBitmap)); 
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);

                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Objects" should be redrawn in Canvas...they doesn't exists in a "floating" form, but like a "real drawn-shape on the paper" and you cannot move a circle after you physically drawn it on paper.

All "move" events are "re-drawn in different position" events